# How to execute hostapd command in cli?

Tags: linux, command-line, android, hostapd, wps

I always got error.
When i execute hostapd command.
I was changed everything in my hostapd.conf file but i got error.

hostapd_cli wps_pbc
Failed to connect to hostapd - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

Can anyone help to me.?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your hostapd.conf file includes:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. But, i did not find var/run . And also it's not created automatically.

Comment: @VINOTHKUMARS there is a `/var/run/hostapd.pid` file when hostapd is running. You probably didn't find it because you either searched for "var/run" without a leading slash or your hostapd service was not running. This answer saved me, should be accepted.